# PhantomJS Fails to Render When Called from PHP

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, phantomjs, vagrant

I have a one-liner that generates a PDF from an HTML file:

```
$my_path = "/path/to/phantomjs/and/generate-pdf.js";
$output  = shell_exec("cd $my_path && phantomjs generate-pdf.js");
```

I can run this command successfully from the shell as the root user, myself, and the apache user (www-data).  Even more, I can run this same line of code successfully from a PHP file called from the command-line as `php generate-pdf.php`, and I'm able to run other shell commands such as `touch test.txt` just fine from an HTTP request.

Why am I unable to generate the PDF when called from an HTTP request?

The entire directory structure (including the phantomjs executable and generate-pdf.js) has been given 777 permissions, `safe_mode` has been disabled from both `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, and `disable_functions` does not include `shell_exec`.

Comment: Can you run the same setup in a test PHP script with your HTML pre-generated?  I'm assuming you have the HTML file hard-coded in your generate-pdf.js?  Because you aren't passing in the info ...

Answer (score 0):

If you made sure that `shell_exec()` itself is enabled, I guess it is a `$PATH` issue. You should execute it given the full path to the phantomjs binary:

```
shell_exec("cd $my_path && /path/to/phantomjs generate-pdf.js");
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Current command is `cd /vagrant/wp-content/plugins/prices/ && /home/vagrant/local/bin/phantomjs /vagrant/wp-content/plugins/prices/generate-pdf.js` with the same result.  This command works on the shell.

Comment: The result is a pdf file saved to `/vagrant/wp-content/plugins/prices/`

Comment: ... which is not present after execution, I assume?